# How to return a filtered result of array inside a documents through a query in mongoose

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking for a query that can return only certain document inside an array of a main document. Below is the collection stored in DB:

```
{
            "_id": "5ed49b42d6fc0c3878c875a2",
            "stockID": "Stock-1",
            "openingBalance": 30000,
            "closingBalance": 29960,
            "userEmail": "kumarshreyas073@gmail.com",
            "stockName": "Coconut",
            "unitMeasure": "Kgs",
            "referenceName": "U16H",
            "gstApplicable": true,
            "rateOfDuty": 15,
            "price": 30,
            "total": 900000,
            "idCounter": 1,
            "transactions": [
                {
                    "particulars": "To demo",
                    "voucherNumber": "1234567",
                    "voucherType": "Sales",
                    "inward": 0,
                    "outward": 10,
                    "_id": "5ed630530de9f419fc45d2ed",
                    "transactionID": "5ed630530de9f419fc45d2eb",
                    "date": "23/05/2020"
                },
                {
                    "particulars": "To demo",
                    "voucherNumber": "1234567",
                    "voucherType": "Sales",
                    "inward": 0,
                    "outward": 10,
                    "_id": "5ed630c72218b03658bf8191",
                    "transactionID": "5ed630c62218b03658bf818f",
                    "date": "23/05/2020"
                },
                {
                    "particulars": "To demo",
                    "voucherNumber": "1234567",
                    "voucherType": "Sales",
                    "inward": 0,
                    "outward": 10,
                    "_id": "5ed64ebd89ee57327cd46772",
                    "transactionID": "5ed64ebd89ee57327cd46770",
                    "date": "23/05/2020"
                },
                {
                    "particulars": "To demo",
                    "voucherNumber": "1234567",
                    "voucherType": "Sales",
                    "inward": 0,
                    "outward": 10,
                    "_id": "5ed64f0cf5891925f0f0a8b1",
                    "transactionID": "5ed64f0cf5891925f0f0a8af",
                    "date": "23/05/2020"
                },
                {
                    "particulars": "To demo",
                    "voucherNumber": "1234567",
                    "voucherType": "Sales",
                    "inward": 0,
                    "outward": 10,
                    "_id": "5ed64f42b56b7d1380df8b70",
                    "transactionID": "5ed64f42b56b7d1380df8b6e",
                    "date": "23/05/2020"
                },
                {
                    "particulars": "To demo",
                    "voucherNumber": "1234567",
                    "voucherType": "Sales",
                    "inward": 0,
                    "outward": 10,
                    "_id": "5ed650674961b126a4092f3f",
                    "transactionID": "5ed650674961b126a4092f3d",
                    "date": "23/05/2020"
                },
                {
                    "particulars": "To demo",
                    "voucherNumber": "U123",
                    "voucherType": "Purchase Return",
                    "inward": 0,
                    "outward": 10,
                    "_id": "5ed72df8f497fb0edc745c4b",
                    "transactionID": "CN-126656",
                    "date": "14/05/2020"
                },
                {
                    "particulars": "To demo",
                    "voucherNumber": "U123",
                    "voucherType": "",
                    "inward": 0,
                    "outward": 10,
                    "_id": "5ed73bf9c922270020db492d",
                    "transactionID": "CN-126665",
                    "date": "14/05/2020"
                },
                {
                    "particulars": "To demo",
                    "voucherNumber": "U123",
                    "voucherType": "Purchase Return",
                    "inward": 0,
                    "outward": 10,
                    "_id": "5ed753a85c61c71e3089f40f",
                    "transactionID": "CN-196700",
                    "date": "14/05/2020"
                },
                {
                    "particulars": "To demo",
                    "voucherNumber": "U123",
                    "voucherType": "Purchase Return",
                    "inward": 0,
                    "outward": 10,
                    "_id": "5ed753ed5c61c71e3089f415",
                    "transactionID": "CN-196000",
                    "date": "14/05/2020"
                },
                {
                    "particulars": "By demo5",
                    "voucherNumber": "1230456",
                    "voucherType": "Purchase",
                    "inward": 50,
                    "outward": 0,
                    "_id": "5ee735e807a0112c9c079d9a",
                    "transactionID": "5ee735e807a0112c9c079d98",
                    "date": "15/06/2020"
                },
                {
                    "particulars": "To demo",
                    "voucherNumber": "12345670",
                    "voucherType": "gdbxdkvghj",
                    "inward": 0,
                    "outward": 10,
                    "_id": "5ee9a4b2b8d4c72440e7a6a1",
                    "transactionID": "5ee9a33a6c1f103fa82992fd",
                    "date": "23/06/2020"
                },
                {
                    "particulars": "To demo1",
                    "voucherNumber": "1234567000",
                    "voucherType": "gdbxdkvghj",
                    "inward": 0,
                    "outward": 20,
                    "_id": "5ee9e28ef327db4358b7465d",
                    "transactionID": "5ee9e15cf327db4358b74651",
                    "date": "17/06/2020"
                }
            ],
            "__v": 0
        }
```

The code Below returns above result:

```
var stockAccount = await Stock.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        userEmail: req.body.userEmail,
      },
    },
    {
      $match: {
        "transactions.date": {
          $gte: req.body.fromDate,
          $lte: req.body.toDate,
        },
      },
    },
  ]);
```

I need to filter the "transactions" array based on date. For example: From "09/05/2020" to "23/05/2020". Expected Output:

```
{
            "_id": "5ed49b42d6fc0c3878c875a2",
            "stockID": "Stock-1",
            "openingBalance": 30000,
            "closingBalance": 29960,
            "userEmail": "kumarshreyas073@gmail.com",
            "stockName": "Coconut",
            "unitMeasure": "Kgs",
            "referenceName": "U16H",
            "gstApplicable": true,
            "rateOfDuty": 15,
            "price": 30,
            "total": 900000,
            "idCounter": 1,
            "transactions": [
                {
                    "particulars": "To demo",
                    "voucherNumber": "1234567",
                    "voucherType": "Sales",
                    "inward": 0,
                    "outward": 10,
                    "_id": "5ed630530de9f419fc45d2ed",
                    "transactionID": "5ed630530de9f419fc45d2eb",
                    "date": "23/05/2020"
                },
                {
                    "particulars": "To demo",
                    "voucherNumber": "1234567",
                    "voucherType": "Sales",
                    "inward": 0,
                    "outward": 10,
                    "_id": "5ed630c72218b03658bf8191",
                    "transactionID": "5ed630c62218b03658bf818f",
                    "date": "23/05/2020"
                },
                {
                    "particulars": "To demo",
                    "voucherNumber": "1234567",
                    "voucherType": "Sales",
                    "inward": 0,
                    "outward": 10,
                    "_id": "5ed64ebd89ee57327cd46772",
                    "transactionID": "5ed64ebd89ee57327cd46770",
                    "date": "23/05/2020"
                },
                {
                    "particulars": "To demo",
                    "voucherNumber": "1234567",
                    "voucherType": "Sales",
                    "inward": 0,
                    "outward": 10,
                    "_id": "5ed64f0cf5891925f0f0a8b1",
                    "transactionID": "5ed64f0cf5891925f0f0a8af",
                    "date": "23/05/2020"
                },
                {
                    "particulars": "To demo",
                    "voucherNumber": "1234567",
                    "voucherType": "Sales",
                    "inward": 0,
                    "outward": 10,
                    "_id": "5ed64f42b56b7d1380df8b70",
                    "transactionID": "5ed64f42b56b7d1380df8b6e",
                    "date": "23/05/2020"
                },
                {
                    "particulars": "To demo",
                    "voucherNumber": "1234567",
                    "voucherType": "Sales",
                    "inward": 0,
                    "outward": 10,
                    "_id": "5ed650674961b126a4092f3f",
                    "transactionID": "5ed650674961b126a4092f3d",
                    "date": "23/05/2020"
                }
            ],
            "__v": 0
        }
```

Is there an query to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe aggregation is not needed in your case.

```
var stockAccount = await Stock.find({
      userEmail: req.body.userEmail,
      "transactions.date": {
        $gte: req.body.fromDate,
        $lte: req.body.toDate,
      }
});
```

**Note:** It seems like the format of the date in the database is a string. So, date comparison should not work.

Comment: I tried this. This query returns record with all transaction.

Comment: Maybe because the value of `fromDate` and `toDate` is not correct?

Comment: @ShreyasKumar It seems like the format of the date in the database is a string. So, date comparison should not work.

Comment: yes. This is why I went for Pipelining. Is there any method.